# com/mysql/jdbc/Driver (unsupported major.minor version 49.0) error in Android emulator

Tags: mysql, mobile, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am developing android app using Oracle mobile ADF that uses MySQL database to retrieve data. I have used JDeveloper 11, MySQL 5.6, jdbc connector-5.1.25, JDK1.7, but still I am getting com/mysql/jdbc/Driver (unsupported major.minor version 49.0) error in Android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Could you run this command and come back to us with result: `java -version`

Comment: java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: It is working fine in console, I am getting correct result, but problem is after deployment on android emulator

Comment: As I understood right android emulator is virtual environment where we can run mobile application and also it has own JDK, could you confirm, pls.

Comment: how to check android emulator jdk version?

Answer (score 0):

Is your database local on your phone or on a remote server.
If it is on a remote server, you can't JDBC into it from ADF Mobile.
You need to go through Web services.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please send an example of adf application that uses REST web service to interact with mysql database